# Vercel, NuxtJS. Error: No Output Directory named "dist" found after the Build completed

Tags: nuxt.js, vercel

I am trying to static host my nuxtjs app on vercel. When I try to deploy the app on my master branch I get this error
`Error: No Output Directory named "dist" found after the Build completed. You can configure the Output Directory in your Project Settings.`
And when I try to deploy my app on a custom branch that I use `npm run dev` and then `npm run deployVercel`

```
"scripts": {
    "deployVercel": "push-dir --dir=dist --branch=vercel --cleanup"
}
```

I get the same no dist folder found error.

Comment: Hi, do you have a public github repo or some `nuxt.config.js` + `package.json` to share please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `push-dir` is supposed to do, but you should have an auto-detection of your Nuxt app by Vercel directly. Check that one: https://vercel.com/guides/deploying-nuxtjs-with-vercel

A `npm run generate` + `npm run start` should be enough too.
`npm run dev` is for local development purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your package.json has "build": "sanity build", under the scripts section Then, try running npm run build from to see if you get any errors.